# Extract Album Art from mp3 and display in an Image with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mp3, id3

I want to do this and I don't want to have an external DLL file used.

Album Art is a picture which is stored in a for example MP3 file. I want to get it out and display it. I searched the net but I couldn't find a source file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should find a source to download the album art from. Then download it. Then display it. With what step do you have a problem? What have you tried already? Try to make your question more specific please.

Answer (score 0):

Album Art in MP3 is supported in ID3v2 tags.

The first Experts Exhange hit on this [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=mp3++ID3V2+delphi) answers how to do that in Delphi.

ID3 has a [list of implementations](http://www.id3.org/Implementations), including Delphi implementations.

--jeroen